# gnuradio OOT mudule “No mudule specified“”

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

when I compile the OOT module successfully, in the list of modules on grc, there are two subclasses, one is "core" and the other is "no modules specified", and my OOT module is under the “no modules specified”. However, when I drag the module into the companion, there is an error, the module has no parameters, input and output, and it is marked in red.
The version of gnuradio is 3.7.13.5 and the version of uhd is 3.10.3, and one of XML of block is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<block>
  <name>reader</name>
  <key>rfid_reader</key>
  <category>[rfid]</category>
  <import>import rfid</import>
  <make>rfid.reader()</make>
  <!-- Make one 'param' node for every Parameter you want settable from the GUI.
       Sub-nodes:
       * name
       * key (makes the value accessible as $keyname, e.g. in the make node)
       * type -->
  <param>
    <name>...</name>
    <key>...</key>
    <type>...</type>
  </param>

  <!-- Make one 'sink' node per input. Sub-nodes:
       * name (an identifier for the GUI)
       * type
       * vlen
       * optional (set to 1 for optional inputs) -->
  <sink>
    <name>in</name>
    <type><!-- e.g. int, float, complex, byte, short, xxx_vector, ...--></type>
  </sink>

  <!-- Make one 'source' node per output. Sub-nodes:
       * name (an identifier for the GUI)
       * type
       * vlen
       * optional (set to 1 for optional inputs) -->
  <source>
    <name>out</name>
    <type><!-- e.g. int, float, complex, byte, short, xxx_vector, ...--></type>
  </source>
</block>
```

I have two block paths, the first one is as follow,which includes all modules provided by gnuradio,

```
/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/
```

the other is as follow, which includes only OOT modules.

```
/usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/
```

My CMakeLists is as follow:

```
install(FILES
    rfid_global_vars.xml
    rfid_gate.xml
    rfid_reader.xml
    rfid_tag_decoder.xml DESTINATION share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
)
```

I think the problem may be:
1 .Is the code of the xml faulty?
2 .Is the code and path of CMakeLists wrong?
3 .Is the path of OOT tree is problematic?
I have been troubled by this problem for a long time. Can someone help me to correct it?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Harder to read and harder to search for than code text that was just copied & pasted into your question and then "code formatted" (using the `{}` button on top of the editor).

Comment: GNU Radio 3.7 is End-Of-Life. It's increasingly hard to support. Please consider porting your software to a more modern version of GNU Radio (3.10 at the time of writing).

Comment: I'm also sorry, but I simply don't understand what the problem is. Can you say, exactly, what is wrong?

Comment: I'm also sorry, I rarely submit issues on Stack Overflow, so I'm not good at this. My problem is that when I compile the OOT module successfully, in the list of modules on grc, there are two subclasses, one is "core" and the other is "no modules specified", and my OOT module is under the “no modules specified”. However, when I drag the module into the companion, there is an error, the module has no parameters, input and output, and it is marked in red.

Comment: Ah! that clarifies it nicely! Can you **edit** your question text to include what you just wrote in the comment? Then, others can see it more easily.